# I'm trying to put a ROM onto my SD card in my phone through USB storage?

Tags: external-sd, rom

But i cant find the folder for my SD card anywhere, does anyone know where i need to put the ROM?

Comment: What type of phone? What version of Android? How are you trying to copy it over? What operating system are you running on the PC you are using (if relevant)? This is not enough information.

Comment: You should be able to mount your SD card to your computer, and it will show up as a separate drive from the internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option is to shut the phone down, remove the SD card, and put it into an SD card reader in your computer. You generally have to reboot into recovery or a bootloader anyway, right?

Typically the folder is /sdcard on the phone's filesystem. If you can put the phone in "Mass Storage" mode (as opposed to Kies or MTP mode or whatever stupid your manufacturer does), it should just be the /sdcard folder.

If you have to flash a recovery or a new bootloader first, you can flash from  /data/local as it is supposed to be user-writable.

If you have adb set up, you can use the `adb push` command.

Answer (score 0):

For my samsung galaxy ace phone, i had to install samsungkies to be able to mount the sd card in the pc, didnt work alone. Maybe is the same with you

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to drop the ROM image anywhere on the SD Card and then use, for instance, [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager) to install it; Just open ROM Manager and select 'Install ROM from SD Card' and browse to where you dumped the ROM **REMEMBER TO BACKUP YOUR EXISTING ROM BEFORE PROCEEDING**